# disable/hide all link button using jquery in repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater, linkbutton

I have a repeater which will have a link button per row here is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_OutstandingBCsForClient" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="pay">
            <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                      <div style="width: 230px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Len" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                 </div>
                   </td>
                  <td align="left">
                  <div style="width: 80px;">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_Remove" runat="server">Remove</asp:LinkButton>

            </div>
              </td>                            
               </tr>
           </table>
          </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to disable or hide all Linkbuttons with id 'lnkbtn_Remove' on button click, so i have done this but still it doesn't work, if put an alert after var linkButton1 I get an object, but it doesn't disable or hide the link button:

```
$("input[id$='btnP']").click(function (e) {
                var linkButton1 = $('[id*="lnkbtn_Remove"]'); 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MyPage.aspx/Take",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg.d.indexOf('https://') > -1) {

                            $('#lnkbtn_Remove').attr("disabled", true);
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    }

                });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id will be changed by asp.net for each link button. Use wild cards.

Change

```
$('#lnkbtn_Remove').attr("disabled", true);
```

To

```
$('[id*=lnkbtn_Remove]').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I can see the disabled attribute in firebug on button set to true after click but still am able to click the button..

Comment: AFAIK To disable anchor you need to remove attribute href or use preventDefault on its click

Answer (score 4):

Because your `LinkButton`s are server-side controls, their client-side IDs will not be `lnkbtn_Remove` but `somethingsomethingsomethinglnkbtn_Remove`.

Thus, try `$('[id$="lnkbtn_Remove"]')` instead of `$('#lnkbtn_Remove')`. `id$=` means "ID ends with".

---

As well as the selector issue, you also apparently can't disable a `LinkButton`, so you need to `.remove()` or `.hide()` it.

Comment: tried this but i dont see the disable attribute using firefox

Comment: The problem could also be that maybe you can't disable a link button? Try a literal `.Remove()` and see if the buttons disappear or not.

Comment: cool this works now with hide() function $('[id*=lnkbtn_Remove]').hide('slow');

Comment: Great, so the selector works at least; I think however you can only _disable_ a `LinkButton` by e.g. clearing out its `OnClick` behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

OnbuttonClick If you want to disable this button then you can use...

```
$('[id*=lnkbtn_Remove]').attr("disabled", true);
```

or if you want to hide this then simply you can use

```
$("#lnkbtn_Remove").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set CSS class for your buttons like "linkButtonRemove", so all link buttons from your repeater will have the same class. I think it's better way than using IDs here...

And then in jquery try to hide found elements:

```
    $('.linkButtonRemove').hide();
```

or through adding css style

```
     $('.linkButtonRemove').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#lnkbtn_Remove').click(function(){return false;})
```